# Why I get a very low accuracy with LSTM and pretrained word2vec?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, keras, nlp

I'm working on a reviews classification model with only two categories 0 (negative) and 1 (positive). I'm using pre-trained word2vec from google with LSTM. The problem is I get an accuracy of around 50% where it should be around 83% according to [this paper](http://unitech-selectedpapers.tugab.bg/2018/papers/s4_p218.pdf). I tried many different hyperparameters combination and still gets a horrible accuracy. I also tried to change the data preprocessing techniques and tried stemming but it hasn't resolved the problem

here's my code

```
X, y = read_data()
X = np.array(clean_text(X)) #apply data preprocessing  
tokenizer = Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(X)

#converts text to sequence and add padding zeros
sequence = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(X)
X_data = pad_sequences(sequence, maxlen = length, padding = 'post')

X_train, X_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(X_data, y, test_size = 0.2)

#Load the word2vec model
word2vec = KeyedVectors.load_word2vec_format(EMBEDDING_FILE, binary=True)

word_index = tokenizer.word_index
nb_words = min(MAX_NB_WORDS, len(word_index))+1

embedding_matrix = np.zeros((nb_words, EMBEDDING_DIM))
null_words = []
for word, i in word_index.items():
    if word in word2vec.wv.vocab:
        embedding_matrix[i] = word2vec.word_vec(word)
    else:
        null_words.append(word)

embedding_layer = Embedding(embedding_matrix.shape[0], # or len(word_index) + 1
                            embedding_matrix.shape[1], # or EMBEDDING_DIM,
                            weights=[embedding_matrix],
                            input_length=701,
                            trainable=False)

model = Sequential()
model.add(embedding_layer)
model.add(LSTM(100))
model.add(Dropout(0.4))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='sigmoid'))
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
```

I also tried other optimizers like AdaMax and MSLE loss function. I'm just confused if the problem isn't with the model and preprocessing where could it be? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

**Its huge discrepancy, I suspect a lie.**

While +33% can be achieved, you said that you tried very different architectures and you did not get even close. **Dont expect that one tweak, one layer, one xyz can give you all of a suddenly such a huge increase.** If you did not get closer using suggestions from the paper there is also a ***possibility*** (not saying they did, but it has been done before in ML papers- lying about accuracy achieved without providing code) that **they lied**.